# Celery with rabbitmq creates results multiple queues

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have installed Celery with RabbitMQ.
Problem is that for every result that is returned, Celery will create in the Rabbit, queue with the task's ID in the exchange celeryresults.

I still want to have results, but on ONE queue.

my celeryconfig:

```
from datetime import timedelta
OKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
#CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json', 'application/json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Oslo'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-minute': {
        'task': 'tasks.remote',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': (),
    },
}
```

Is that possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: hard to guess without seeing your code... celery config and how you create the queue, send tasks etc.

Answer (score 9):

**amqp** backend creates a new queue for each task. Alternatively, there is a new **rpc** backend which keeps results in a single queue.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/whatsnew-3.1.html#new-rpc-result-backend

Comment: do I need to configure Rabbit with anything special in order to listen RPC?

Comment: No, there's no need to configure Rabbit. Add `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'` to your `celery_config.py` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing unusual.

That is how celery works when we use amqp as result backend. It will create a new temporary queue for every result corresponding to each tasks that worker consumes.

If you are not interested in the result, you can try CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True setting

If you do want to store the result, then i would recommend using a different result backend like Redis.

Comment: How temporary is this queue? I just checked and I have over 10,000 queues with over 25,000 messages.

Comment: I think by default it is 24 hours.....you can try by setting CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=<time in secs> for that. Let me know how it works?

Comment: Although with 10000 queues and 25000 messages, it seems like a large scale app. Do consider other backends. I also tried rabbitmq result backend first, then due to these reasons, shifted to redis.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want Celery to keep the result on one queue. Now, to answer your question, let me ask you one:

How do you expect each producer to check for it's relevant result without reading every single message off the queue to find the one it needs/wants?

In essence, what you want is a database of key-value pairs so that the lookup is O(1). The only way to do that with a queue broker is to create one queue for each "pair".

I understand that having many GUID queues is not neat or pretty, but it's conceptually the only way to do it on a messaging broker.

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't keep all the results to ONE queue, but it will at least clean up the extra queues right when you're done with them.

If you use Redis as your backend, when you're done with a result that has created an errant queue, run result.forget(). This will cause both the result and the queue for the result to disappear. This can help you manage the number of queues you have, and prevent OOM issues.