# New RabbitMQ Queue being created for every celery task

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using celery 3.1 with rabbitmq as broker.
Issue is when I publish a task (i.e task.delay()) message is getting 
created in rabbitmq with reply-to header containg uniqueid (say 123). 
Due to this rabbitmq is creating a queue with name as 123 and this is happening for every task that is published.

Say if I run a task for 10 times, 10 reply queues are getting created.   I don't even want reply to go to rabbitmq and currently I configured  CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND as rpc.Here is the configuration

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost//' 
  CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'

Task
      @app.task(name="tasks.multiplynumbers",bind=True,default_retry_delay=5,max_retries=2,serializer='json',acks_late=True,track_started=True)

def multiply(self,x, y):

```
try:

    return x * y

except Exception as exc:

    raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

Here is the message :

reply_to:        **40872e4f-10fc-313d-a48d-13aa94419f20**

correlation_id:  25d6f28a-9b18-49c0-950c-19af7af52770

priority:        0

delivery_mode:   2

headers: 
content_encoding: utf-8

content_type:    application/json

Payload

265 bytes
Encoding: string
{"taskset": null, "task": "reotasks.multiplynumbers", "errbacks": null, "timelimit": [null, null], "callbacks": null, "utc": true, "chord": null, "expires": null, "args": [3, 8], "retries": 0, "id": "25d6f28a-9b18-49c0-950c-19af7af52770", "eta"

when the above message is published then a queue with name **40872e4f-10fc-313d-a48d-13aa94419f20**  is getting created.

Did anyone encounter this situation?  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998658/celery-with-rabbitmq-creates-results-multiple-queues/23290331

Answer (score 1):

After further research, I figured out when celery_result_backend is set to 'rpc://' and use rabbitmq as broker, it seems that  every task is published with reply-to header and a new queue gets created based on the information in below link:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html

It would be good if we can have some control on to which queue to publish the results and any best practices to deal with